# I need help sending custom information to session.user object using next-auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth, next.js13

Im tryng to add custom data to the session.user but it doesnt work. The odd thing is that if I send this:

```
const user = { id: '1', name: "J Smith", email: "jsmith@example.com", };
```

Then I receive that information on my page.jsx using useSession and print it in the console:

```
const { data: session } = useSession(); console.log("in form session: ", session);
```

But the problem is when I try to add custom information to the user:

```
const user = { userId: res.data.data.login.userId, companyId: res.data.data.login.companyId, };
```

It printing empty the user object, without the custom information, only works when I use id, name, and email.

This is my full code:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import axios from "axios";

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "Enter your email",
        },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const res = await axios({
          method: "POST",
          url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_URL}/api`,
          data: {
            query: `
              query Login($email: String!, $password: String!) {
                login(email: $email, password: $password) {
                  userId
                  token
                  tokenExpiration
                  companyId
                }
              }
            `,
            variables: {
              email: credentials.email,
              password: credentials.password,
            },
          },
        });
        // Validation
        if (res.data.errors) {
          throw new Error(res.data.errors[0].message);
        }
        const user = {
          userId: res.data.data.login.userId,
          companyId: res.data.data.login.companyId,
        };
        if (user) {
          return user;
        }
        // // Return null if user data could not be retrieved
        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
    signOut: "/logout",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Someone knows how to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the jwt callback, which will receive the user from the Credentials provider, and the session callback that will expose the data you need in the client (eg. `useSession`)

I already fix it, I post my answer here, maybe its help someone in the future.
I was missing the jwt and session callback and the session callback. Because next-auth by default don't expose everything for security reasons.

Adding this fix it:

```
callbacks: {
  async jwt({ token, user }) {
    // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin
    if (user) {
      token.accessToken = user.token;
    }
    return token;
  },
  async session({ session, token, user }) {
    // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.
    session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
    return session;
  },
},
```

And that callbacks will expose the access token to the client.